# running batch file on network drive

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write an VBA code that will run a batch file that is located in a network drive, here's what I have now:

```
Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /c \\networkdrive\c$\Test\Test.bat", vbNormalFocus)
```

When I run the script, it brings up the command prompt but it won't be able to get to the network drive because cmd doesn't recognize the synthax \networkdrive\c$\Test... Does anyone know how to deal with this issue?

Comment: I usually just use `\\networkdrive\C$\Test\Test.bat, vbHide` Shell is smart enough to run it without having to specify cmd.exe. without any of the proceeding values.

Comment: i still get the same error, the system cannot find the path specified

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it works for me.

`Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /c start \\networkdrive\c$\Test\Test.bat", vbNormalFocus)`

The problem being that the console remains open...

Comment: It's not the same... it calls start. Sorry it didn't work for you.